# Springmvc RequestMapping accept any character in any language

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-mvc

I need to use a regex in `@RequestMapping` value so that it can accept Japanese character as well as English character.

I tried this -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Attendance_Report{[a-z0-9_\\p{Hiragana}\\p{Katakana}]+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Its not working while Japanese character present in the URL. But the following is working without Japanese character in request url -

`@RequestMapping(value = "/Attendance_Report{[a-z0-9_]+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

What should I put exactly in value attribute to meet my requirements?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should leave the value as it is (i.e. `'/Attendance_Report'`), like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Attendance_Report", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

In order to accept characters in both English (ISO-8859-1) and Japanese (UTF-8) in the URI, I think it is the matter of the application server (e.g. Tomcat) configuration. For example, if you deploy on Tomcat, you should set the `URIEncoding` to `"UTF-8"`, like this.

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" ..>
```

Comment: <Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" port="8181" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />............... I tried this and the above said RequestMapping. But its giving HTTP 400.

Comment: What does your request url look like?